# how to get the user's input in kotlin on android studio

Tags: android

I have an android project that shows a summary of you car efficiency on which you enter your information and it shows in a listView your summary, but how do I get the user's input, so I can do the math, and show the sum on a different activity?

```
fun getTotalGallons() : Double {
        // add all of the gallons together from the list
        // return that total
        return ....
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show more of your code and the error message you get

Answer (score 0):

val editText = EditText() //Here you can use instantiate it or use kotlin 
                          //extensions to used it directly

val stringText = editText.text //do something

Comment: this is what I've been doing but it's not letting me `fun getTotalGallons() : Double {
        // add all of the gallons together from the list
        // return that total
        val totalGas += gallonsText.text.toString().toDouble()
        return totalGas
    }`

Comment: Can you provide me more information? The classes, the logic?